# Change domain name URL to http://preprod.nom.fr/directory/

Tags: url, prestashop

My problem: I want to change the domain name url `site.com` to `preprod.nom.fr/directory` for testing before going to production phase.
I have modified the table `shop_url` (`site.com`) to `preprod.nom.fr/directory` without success.

Comment: Sur ce site-web les questions ne sont demandés qu'en anglais.

Comment: Good evening everyone

My problem: I want to change the domain name url (site.com) to http://preprod.nom.fr/nomdosiier/ for testing before production

I modify the table shop_url (site.com) to http://preprod.nom.fr/nomdosiier/

But no result, thank you for help me please

Comment: Edit the question please, don't write your question as a comment

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in the Preferences tab -> seo & url -> Store URL
URl of the shop?
Base Path?

Regards